# How to count the process using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to count how many times that I check the result.
This the part of the process looks like:

```
function GetValueResult
{
   ...Some Process...
   $Result = $ReturnCode
}

GetValueResult

if ($Result -eq 0)
{
   Write-Host "The process Pass"
   Restart-Computer
}
elseif ($Result -eq 1)
{
   Write-Host "Try again"
   GetValueResult

   #This part I need to know how many times that I call this function  "GetValueResult"

}
```

Anyone can help me how to count how many times that I call the function "GetValueResult"?
If it already 3 times, than I need to do further action. Thanks for help.

Comment: I guess you missing some details as I suspect that the `counter` needs to survive a `Restart-Computer` in which case I would use the registry for keeping track of your `counter`. In which case it is also good to know if it conserns the SYSTEM account or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a simple loop inside your function and output an object with both the ResultCode and the number of tries:

```
function GetValueResult {
    # initialize to error code
    $ResultCode = -1
    for ($numTries = 0; $numTries -lt 3; $numTries++) {
        # ...Some Process...

        # exit the loop if we have a correct $ResultCode
        if ($ResultCode -eq 0) { break }
        Write-Host "Try again"
    }
    # output an object with the resultcode and the number of tries
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ResultCode = $ResultCode
        Tries      = $numTries + 1
    }
}

$result = GetValueResult
if ($result.ResultCode -eq 0) {
   Write-Host "The process Pass"
   Restart-Computer
}
else {
    Write-Host "Bad result after $($result.Tries) tries.."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use increment for this purpose.

```
$Result = 0
foreach (...){
   $Result++
   if ($Result -ge 3){
      ...your action...
   }
}
```

Also, I can't find any loop in your script, so how would you count in this case? Please share more details about what are you trying to achieve with it, perhaps you need to redesign it from the beginning.